# Continuously looping through an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to work out how to continuously loop through an array, but apparently using `foreach` doesn't work as it works on a copy of the array or something along those lines.

I tried:

```
$amount = count($stuff);
$last_key = $amount - 1;

foreach ($stuff as $key => $val) {

    // Do stuff

    if ($key == $last_key) {
        // Reset array cursor so we can loop through it again...
        reset($stuff);
    }

}
```

But obviously that didn't work. What are my choices here?

Comment: What is your base case for this loop? When would it stop?

Comment: Is the loop ever supposed to end?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You surely don't just want a loop to run forever hence making the script endless?

Comment: Of course it is going to stop, but I didn't see a need to detail that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop will never stop:

```
while(true) {
    // do something
}
```

If necessary, you can break your loop like this:

```
while(true) {
    // do something
    if($arbitraryBreakCondition === true) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you could also stop the loop by doing `break;` as well? :)

Comment: Absolutely, I'll modify :-)

Answer (score 5):

An easy way is to combine an [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/arrayiterator) with an [InfiniteIterator](http://php.net/infiniteiterator).

```
$infinite = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
foreach ($infinite as $key => $val) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this with a [`while`](http://php.net/while) loop:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($stuff)) {
    // code
    if ($key == $last_key) {
        reset($stuff); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one using reset() and next():

```
$total_count = 12;
$items = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$value = reset($items);
echo $value;
for ($j = 1; $j < $total_count; $j++) {
    $value = ($next = next($items)) ? $next : reset($items);
    echo ", $value";
};
```

Output:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4

I was rather surprised to find no such native function. This is a building block for a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop and just set a condition that's always going to be true - for example:

```
$amount = count($stuff);
$last_key = $amount - 1;

for($key=0;1;$key++)
{
    // Do stuff
    echo $stuff[$key];

    if ($key == $last_key) {
        // Reset array cursor so we can loop through it again...
        $key= -1;
    }


}
```

Obviously, as other's have pointed out - make sure you've got something to stop the looping before you run that!

Comment: should you reset it to "-1" as the for construct adds to the counter at the END of the loop!? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using a function and return false in a while loop:

```
function stuff($stuff){
   $amount = count($stuff);
   $last_key = $amount - 1;

   foreach ($stuff as $key => $val) {

       // Do stuff

       if ($key == $last_key) {
           // Reset array cursor so we can loop through it again...
           return false;
       }

   }
}

while(stuff($stuff)===FALSE){
    //say hello
}
```

Comment: Execute the function on each iteration? Do you think that's a good idea?

Comment: First of all I am not sure executing a continuous loop is the best option. But in that case I gess my suggestion is similar to yours because the function is executed when `$key == $last_key` into the `foreach`